# windows 2019 unattended install on kvm via libvirt can't find licence error

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, unattended, packer

I'm trying to install windows server 2019 with autounattend.xml configuration on kvm via libvirt.

Installation fail on dialog with sign: "Can't find microsoft software license terms"

Despite there are a lot of articles with solving this error - it doesn't work for me. The main difference in my case is that I can successfully install windows manually, but I get this error on unattended installation only.

I'm using packer to build VM image, and with qemu builder it works, with libvirt builder doesn't. And this issue isn't related to packer - I've created VM manually and got the same error.
I've played with VM configuration trying to set/remove different parameters but no luck as well.
I've installed windows10 the same way (unattended) without any issue.

So, looks like it isn't an ISO image issue - I can install from the same iso manually or via qemu builder
It doesn't seen to be an error in autounattend.xml - I use the same file for qemu installation and for windows10

Currently I'm stuck. So if anybody has any suggestions, I'll appreciate.

UPDATE: windows 2019 installation doesn't work on qemu and on libvirt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was in autounattended.xml file configuration - Windows 2019 installation fails with specified error if unattended file contains empty parameter "". For Windows2019 that string should be removed:

```
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    ...
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup"...
    ...
      <UserData>
      ...
        <ProductKey>
          <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
          <Key></Key>  <------ REMOVE FOR Windows2019 this line
        </ProductKey>
    ...
```

From other side, Windows10 requires presence of that string ("")